I want to run a Java program through Jenkins using Shell command , but getting below error
I am getting below error while running a Java program through jenkins, I am using Ubantu OS:
Started by user kuldeep singh
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HelloWorld
[HelloWorld] $ /bin/sh /tmp/jenkins4618265422787028347.sh
/tmp/jenkins4618265422787028347.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /home/ironman/Desktop/GitDemo2
error: file not found: Hello.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

I used these commands in Build Steps of jenkins while running using through Shell command:
cd /home/ironman/Desktop/GitDemo2
sudo javac Hello.java
java Hello


Is the directory you're trying to access even present on your jenkins server? For me this looks like a directory on your local machine.

The error says the script can not CD to your directory. That is probably because the user that executes Jenkins doesn't has the permission to a subdirectory of your home directory. Try a directory somewhere else that the Jenkins user actually has access.
